# JavaFX locale bundle: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, javafx, localization

I have JavaFX application with localization. However, I can't make it work as FXML Loader is unable to find localization bundle

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name bundles.lcars, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at cz.muni.fi.pv168.view.GUI.start(GUI.java:24)
```

**Structure**:

[image: Project structure]

**Main GUI class:**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.lcars", locale));
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("lcars.fxml"),ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles" +
            ".lcars", locale));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1920 , 1080);   // 19:10
    // set scene to stage and other irrelevant stuff

}
```

I also tried to move bundles folder to root package, without success. Also, I tried every already answered question to query "can't find bundle for base name".

**EDIT for @Slaw**
I changed code to this, still no success

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("lcars.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.lcars", locale));
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: In your code you create a `FXMLLoader` instance and use `setResources` on it. Then you proceed to use the _static_ `FXMLLoader.load(URL, ResourceBundle)` method. This makes creating the instance useless.

Comment: THank you for comment, but setResources cannot be referenced from static context and load() is static, on the contrary

Comment: The `FXMLLoader.load()` method is an _instance_ method. You should be calling `Parent root = fxmlLoader.load()`. However, you'll have to set the location first either using `fxmlLoader.setLocation(URL)` or using the constructor: `new FXMLLoader(URL)`. Or, if you don't want to use an instance, you can simply get rid of `fxmlLoader` and stick  with the _static_ methods.

Comment: I edited my question with code update regarding your proposed changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ResourceBundle class:

```
private static ResourceBundle language = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
        "cz.muni.fi.pv168.gui.GUI", Locale.getDefault());
```

my file structure is like this:

[image]

From this you should get the idea of how it is set up.

You reference the localized strings like this:

```
language.getString("agentsEmptyBirthDateMessage")
```

Comment: Thank you, my good sir, live long and prosper. Just in time you posted your answer I found it works with full package path, just like your answer has :)